# Getting only the last array data when i looped all arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to use Facebook Graph API to get comments from the last 2 posts from my accounts
I wrote the code and it works but it only returns the second post (the last array) only

this my code :

```
$postItems = $postsArray['posts']['data'];
foreach ($postItems as $post) {
    $fullPostId = $post['id'];
    $comments_number = 10;
    $facebook_graph_api2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/$fullPostId/comments?access_token=$accToken&pretty=1&summary=true&limit=$comments_number&after";
    $jsonData = grab_page($facebook_graph_api2,$accCookie);
    $postDataArrays = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    $CommentsItems = $postDataArrays['data'];
}
//foreach($CommentItems as $item) {
    //  echo $users = $item['from']['id'].'\n';
//}

// @$postItems = $postsArray['data'];
/** Update Balance Code **/
$toolId = '87637';
@$itemsCount = @count($CommentItems);
$toolPrice = toolPrice($toolId)*$itemsCount;
$finalBalance = updateBalance($toolPrice);

/** Update Balance Code **/
if ($finalBalance) {
    if (isset($CommentItems)) {
        echo '{"status":1,"balance":'.$finalBalance.',"message":"Success !","data":"';
        foreach($CommentItems as $item) {
            echo $users = $item['from']['id'].'\n';
            // echo  json_encode($users, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
            // $items[] = $item['from']['id'];
        }
        // print_r($items);
        // echo '{"status":1,"message":"Success !","data":"'.$items.'"}';
        echo '"}';
    }elseif( isset($postDataArray['error']) && $postDataArray['error']['code']== 1 ){
        $msgError = $postDataArray['error']['message'];
        echo '{"status":0,"message":"Error !","reason":"'.$msgError.'"}';

    }else{
        echo '{"status":0,"message":"Error !","reason":"Please Update Your Facebook Access Token"}';
    }
}else{
    echo '{"status":0,"message":"Error !","reason":"You do not have enough funds on balance"}';
}
```

The code above returns only last array data not all posts data.
this is an example of $postDataArrays data should be

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 2023-02-08T14:46:12+0000
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Name1
                            [id] => id1
                        )

                    [message] => test Message
                    [id] => 61xxxxxxxxxxx_12xxxxxxxxxxxx
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 2023-02-08T14:42:52+0000
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name2
                            [id] => id2
                        )

                    [message] => test Message
                    [id] => 61xxxxxxxxxx_7xxxxxxxxxxxx
                )

        )

    [paging] => Array
        (
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/92xxxxxxxxxxxx_61xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments?access_token=EAAG&pretty=1&summary=true&limit=2&after
        )

    [summary] => Array
        (
            [order] => ranked
            [total_count] => 58
            [can_comment] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 2023-02-07T18:23:40+0000
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name1 from array 2
                            [id] => id2 from array 2
                        )

                    [message] => test Message
                    [id] => 6xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 2023-02-07T18:20:49+0000
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => name2 from array 2
                            [id] => id2 from array 2
                        )

                    [message] => test Message
                    [id] => 6xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx
                )

        )

    [paging] => Array
        (
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments?access_token=EAAG&pretty=1&summary=true&limit=2&after
        )

    [summary] => Array
        (
            [order] => ranked
            [total_count] => 121
            [can_comment] => 1
        )

)
```

the arrays above should return 4 users but it returns only last 2 users

Comment: Logic fail: Move the second `foreach` inside the first `foreach`. Otherwise you're only looping over the value `$CommentItems` after the last time the first loop ran. If you put it inside, it will run every time `$CommentItems` is refreshed (i.e. every time the first loop iterates).

Comment: @ADyson i can't put second foreach inside the first one , becuase i return this data in json Like the code after it has been modified in the question above, and i handle the data using javascript and There will be errors

Comment: Your first foreach overwrites `CommentsItems` each time round the loop so you will only get the LAST occurance from that

Comment: See you have had to silence errors on `@$itemsCount = @count($CommentItems);` because `$CommentItems` IS NOT AN ARRAY and you cannot `count()` on a scalar

Comment: **DANGER** Please try and avoid building JSON Strings manually! Make an array and then `json_encode()` it

Comment: I would say not to try to create your own JSON and instead use `json_encode()`.   You need to build the data in an array and then encode that array.  There are things like double quotes `"` and other stuff that could spoil your JSON if it's in the data.

Comment: @egam321 Agreed, the second logic fail is here building JSON by hand, and also echoing data before you've finished processing it. Go through all the data, make a decision about each one, add something to your final result variable each time, with then at the end encode the whole thing to JSON, and then echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i create an array

```
$responses= array();
```

And modified the code and put all neded data inside the array

```
foreach ($postItems as $post) {
    $fullPostId = $post['id'];
    $comments_number = 3000;
    $facebook_graph_api2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/$fullPostId/comments?access_token=$accToken&pretty=1&summary=true&limit=$comments_number&after";
    $jsonData = grab_page($facebook_graph_api2,$accCookie);
    $postDataArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    $CommentsItems = $postDataArray['data'];
    foreach($CommentsItems as $item) {
        $users = $item['from']['id'];
        $userId['user_id'] = $users;
        $responses[] = $userId['user_id'];
    }


}
```

Then , Encoded the the final response to be json , and i decoded it again

```
$enResponse = json_encode($responses);
$allComments = json_decode($enResponse,true);
```

To show all data , just loop $allComments

```
foreach($allComments as $item) {
   echo $users = $item.'\n';
}
```